# ManyToOne / OneToMany with custom join column

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm working with an existing database, with fields that don't relate super well. I've been able to get other ManyToOne and vice versa relationships to work (ones where I created the database while working on the project), but this pre-existing database is throwing me for a loop.

I have a table called `franchisee_creds`, ManyToOne, with a field `franchisee_id` that needs to map to another table called `accounts`, OneToMany, with a field called `franchisee_number`, a string.

`FranchiseeCreds.php`:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     targetEntity="Inertia\InertiaBundle\Entity\Accounts",
 *     inversedBy="franchiseeCreds",
 *     fetch="EAGER"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="franchisee_id", referencedColumnName="franchisee_number")
 */
private $accounts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->accounts = new ArrayCollection();
}

...

 /**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAccounts()
{
    return $this->accounts;
}
```

`Accounts.php`

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Inertia\InertiaBundle\Entity\FranchiseeCreds", mappedBy="accounts")
 */
private $franchiseeCreds;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
}

...

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFranchiseeCreds()
{
    return $this->franchiseeCreds;
}
```

Controller:

```
  public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('inertia');

    $entity = $em->getRepository('InertiaBundle:Accounts')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Accounts entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('InertiaBundle:Accounts:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Then in my views if I put `{{ dump(entities) }}`, on the Accounts and FranchiseeCreds `show.html.twig`, the relationship shows up, but it's always `null`.

Comment: What are you doing on the controller and what are you passing to Twig view?

Comment: I added the controller. The twig view is just the auto-generated one, i just added {{ dump(entity) }} to it so I can see what data i'm given.

Comment: Based on your controller, `{{ dump(entities) }}` does nothing... because you are not passing any `entities` variable to your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I was having was due to doctrine not being able to add foreign keys to the tables while data was in them when I ran:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I made a backup, truncated the tables with problems, reran the `doctrine:schema:update` command, restored the data and everything worked just peachy.

I also had the misconception that I would be able to see an array of related items when I put `{{ dump(entity) }}` in my code.  I was mistaken. When I actually went to the work to run a for loop and print out the data it worked fine, after I had fixed the database.

Comment: You trunacted them with problems? ;)